# Some questions regarding __init_ errors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, init

I got the error : TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attack'

```
    class Unit:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
     
    class Power(Unit):
        def __init__(self, name, attack):
            Unit.__init__(self, name)
            self.attack = attack
            supatt = attack * 2
            print("{0} has a power of {1} and it can develop {1} 
            of its superpowers".format(self.name, attack, supatt))

    class Ground(Power):
        def __init__(self, name, attack, velocity, friction):
            Power.__init__(self, attack)
            self.velocity = velocity
            self.friction = friction
            totalv = velocity - fiction 
            print("{0} : Groud Attack. \nTotal Speed : {1}.\n 
            Power : {2}.".format(self.name, totalv, attack))
    
    class Sky(Power):
        def __init__(self, name, attack, skyspeed, airres):
            Power.__init__(self, attack)
            self.skyspeed = skyspeed
            self.airres = airres
            totalss = skyspeed - airres
            print("{0} : Sky Attack. \nTotal Speed : {1}.\n Power 
            : {2}.".format(self.name, totalss, attack))

    
    valkyrie = Sky("Valkyrie", 200, 300, 150)
    print(valkyrie)
```

The error comes in the `Sky(Power)` class where I wrote :
`Power.__init__(self, attack)`

I thought I already wrote `attack` here. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Your Power class is also expecting 2 parameters and you provided only 1. Since both are positional, its still expecting something to be passed to 'attack'

Comment: Looks like you simply forgot to pass `name` up the hierarchy as well.

Comment: `Power.__init__(self,name, attack)`

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to inherit the Power Class to every other class except for the Unit class.

You want to inherit the classes using the super() function.

```
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Power(Unit):
    def __init__(self, name, attack):
        Unit.__init__(self, name)
        self.attack = attack
        supatt = attack * 2
        print("{0} has a power of {1} and it can develop {1} of its 
        superpowers".format(self.name, attack, supatt))

class Sky(Power):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, skyspeed, airres):
        super().__init__(self, attack)
        self.skyspeed = skyspeed
        self.airres = airres
        totalss = skyspeed - airres
        print("{0} : Sky Attack. \nTotal Speed : {1}.\n Power: 
        {2}.".format(self.name, totalss, attack))

class Ground(Power):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, velocity, friction):
        super().__init__(self, attack)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.friction = friction
        totalv = velocity - friction
        print("{0} : Groud Attack. \nTotal Speed : {1}.\nPower : 
        {2}.".format(self.name, totalv, attack))


valkyrie = Sky("Valkyrie", 200, 300, 150)
print(valkyrie)
```